# How to remove (avoid) focus in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, focus

I want to avoid focus coming on wpf `Grid` for that I have tried:

```
<Grid Focusable="False" />
```

but it is not working. I also tried with:

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid" Focusable="False" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" />
```

but I again failed. How can I avoid focus coming on `Grid`?

Comment: Where is the `Grid`? He root, or it is somewhere? This construction should work, give more information.

Comment: @Anatoliy The grid is at root

Comment: `Grid` is in the `Window`, or in `UserControl` (or elsewhere)?

Comment: and how are you testing the Focus of the Grid?

Comment: Grid is inside the UserControl and I am testing focus of grid by pressing the TAB key. I am wondering that why focusable=false is not working.

Comment: Do you use `ContentControl` or the like? They can take the focus, ie they `Focusable = "True"` by default.

Comment: yes I am loading My UserControl with in a Content control thats why it may getting focused. I will check.

Answer (score 8):

`ContentControl` has a default `Focusable="True"`, because `Control` base class overrides the metadata of the Focusable property and sets its default to true - [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.control%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Just set the value to *false*:

```
<ContentControl Focusable="False" />
```

To keep track of where it comes focus, [`Snoop`](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) a wonderful program. In it, you can find the source of focus.

Comment: Thank you so much Anatoliy Nikolaev I will try with it and let you know about result.